# Core Data valueForKeyPath returns 0

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have a Core Data project with a sort of "master" entity that holds a year value (int 16) and a few other values. There are a few other "child" entities with many-to-one relationships to this one master. In one of those other entities, I want to set a couple of default values, which are a start and end date. The default values should be the beginning and end of the year assigned to the master entity. So I've used this:

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert {
    int currentYear = [[self valueForKeyPath: @"master.year"] intValue];
    NSString *currentYearStart = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d-01-01 00:00:01 +0000", currentYear];
    NSString *currentYearEnd = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d-12-31 23:59:59 +0000", currentYear];
    [self setStartDate: [NSDate dateWithString: currentYearStart]];
    [self setEndDate: [NSDate dateWithString: currentYearEnd]];    
}
```

When I run this, currentYear always ends up being 0, even though the value of master's "year" attribute is 2011. I've tried setting "int currentYear = 2011" and then the code works as expected, so the problem seems to be in the first line. The strange thing is, inside the master entity's subclass of NSManagedObject, I have lines like:

```
float total = [[self valueForKeyPath: @"child.@sum.amount"] floatValue];
```

and this always returns the right amount. I don't see what the difference is. Can anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that master is set at the time your method is called? Also, the awakeFromInsert docs indicate that you must call `[super awakeFromInsert]` first.

Comment: Calling [super awakeFromInsert] doesn't seem to change anything. Also, the child objects are added and removed by clicking buttons, and the NSArrayController the add and remove buttons bind to has its content set as master.selection.child, so the master must exist when the awakeFromInsert call is made.

Comment: Are you sure about that? What happens if you log ```[self valueForKeyPath:@"master"]``` there? What about ```[self valueForKeyPath:@"master.year"]```?

Comment: Well, you may be right, but I still don't understand. The log gives me 

2011-12-03 18:00:24.860 MyProg[1565:707] master = (null)
2011-12-03 18:00:26.024 MyProg[1565:707] master.year = (null)

But the add button is bound to "canAdd" for the Child Array Controller, and like I said, the Array Controller is bound to master.selection.child. So "canAdd" isn't true until master has a selection, which means master.year exists at that point... I'm so confused.

Comment: The issue is that the insert of the new object occurs before its master property is set. (The insert is the first thing that happens with a managed object, before any properties are set.) You probably want to subclass the array controller and override ```- newObject``` to do set the default dates at that point. (i.e. call ```[super newObject]```, then set the default date on the returned object.)

Comment: I see - master exists, but the relationship hasn't been "plugged in" yet. Well, I made a new class ChildController:NSArrayController, set it as the class for the Child Controller in the nib, overrode `-newObject`, called `(id) object = [super newObject]`, then used code like above, replacing `self` with `object`. The function wasn't even called for some reason. I thought that might be because Core Data handles the objects instead of the Array Controller, so I overrode `-add:(id) sender`, but it still didn't get called...

Comment: That might warrant another question; I'm not as familiar with Cocoa bindings as with Core Data itself.

Comment: Thanks, anyway, you still taught me something about timing of methods!